# How does Odoo select the database when starting?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I'm confused about how Odoo selects the database to use when starting the server.

I have a few databases.  The database `todo` is the database that I'm using to develop my application.  The only app that I have installed in the `todo` database is my `todo` app.  I started my server through PowerShell (I'm on Windows) using `./odoo-bin.exe -d todo -u todo_app --test-enable`  From my understanding, this should start the server using the `todo` database.  However, when I look at `odoo.log`, I see a bunch of tests running from other apps that aren't installed in the `todo` database.  Those apps and tests are installed in a different database.

If I go to `/web/database/selector` and select my `todo` database, then restart my server, it works as expected with only the tests in my `todo` database running, and only the `todo` app showing as being installed on the Odoo web page.

It seems like Odoo is ignoring the `-d` flag to `odoo-bin` and always using the last database that I selected through the web page.

Is that how it's supposed to work and am I wrong about how the `-d` flag works?

How do I get Odoo to select its database from `odoo-bin` rather than having to go to `/web/database/selector` change databases after starting the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` flag doesn't mean select automatically that database it tells odoo to create that database if it's not there and run upgrade on **todo** if it's installed (`-u todo`).

You can use `dbfilter` option to use only one database. Example:

```
--db-filter='todo'
```

> I'm on my phone sorry for my short answer